# Example code to execute a ETL Execute API on GoodData using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, etl, gooddata

At developer.gooddata.com there is a great example coded in Ruby on how to upload data to a project specific storage at GoodData platform.

I was wondering if someone has an example of code to execute a specific process a GoodData using the following API:

```
/gdc/projects/{project-id}/dataload/processes/{process-id}/executions{?offset,limit}
```

Thanks,
Michel

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it programmatically is using ruby sdk (github.com/gooddata/gooddata-ruby).

There are methods for uploading to user and project based staging through

```
project.upload_file('some_file')
client.upload_file('/file')
```

There is also a way to deploy processes and even execute them

```
client = GoodData.connect('username', 'pass')
project = client.projects('project_id')
process = project.deploy_process('path_to_file_or_dir')
process.execute('main.grf', :params => {'foo' => 'bar'})
```

Executing specific process works very similarly

```
client = GoodData.connect('username', 'pass')
project = client.projects('project_id')
process = project.processes('process_id')
process.execute('main.grf', :params => {'foo' => 'bar'})
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to go to GoodData API documentation that has nice feature - code examples:

Go on the following link:

http://docs.gooddata.apiary.io/#post-%2Fgdc%2Fprojects%2F%7Bproject-id%7D%2Fschedules%7B%3Foffset%2Climit%7D

and you can see the "show code sample"

[image: Ruby code example]

and select the **Ruby**. Those code samples are generic, using the same pattern and REST Client, but it can help you. Just double check the URLs if you are using correct server. The url will the most probably be https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc...

JT